# KDE4 Amarok 2.1 Drag'n'Drop ipod

Tags: ipod, kde, amarok, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to drag and drop files into it? Or is there a way to put songs into an ipod without adding them into my collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `kio_ipodslave`. Access your iPod with the ipod:/ virtual file system.

Comment: it doesn't add d'n'd feature. And I still need to have music in my collection first to upload it.